# DNN + External Files in FireFox and Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, iis, dotnetnuke

We have a DNN site that we store a number of non-DNN files in. These are generic HTML+JS+CSS files generated by product documentation software. Recently we noticed one of the generations does not load correctly in Chrome 100% of the time and Firefox on occasion. IE does not flake.

By not load correctly, the site never completely loads. The favicon in the browser flickers and/or the process circle continues to spin forever. However, if you switch tabs in the browser, the flicking stops and the assets are loaded. Switch back and you can navigate the documentation.

The files contain a considerable number of javascript calls and redirects. Outside of DNN, the files load without issue. We've scoured to find a way to easily exclude DNN from processing these files, but to no avail.

[www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/visualization/docs/5.5.1/index.html](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/visualization/docs/5.5.1/index.html)

If its of any importance, we do not have control to how the docs are generated (supplied by another source), but the softwares used are Frame 9.0, ePub 2012.2, and Webworks Help 5.0.

**EDIT:** Outside of DNN, the flickering does appear in other parts of the document set at random and/or first load, but is less noticeable and is more difficult to reproduce every load.

Answer (score 1):

Are you by chance running a URL provider outside of the standard DNN provider? You might need to setup filtering to make sure that the URL Provider isn't handling the requests, even though they are non-DNN files.

URLMaster allows for custom regex that will tell it to not handle certain URL formats, in your case you would want to have it ignore from a specific directory down.

You might also check to see if you have Compression enabled in the HOST settings in DNN, if so, turn it off there and let IIS handle compression.

Comment: We are also running URL Master (meant to include that). Excluding the folder of issue, it looks like the issue is no longer occurring. However, what would be the ultimate reason why URL Master has issues with these files? Other sets generated by the same program do not have the same negative results.

Comment: That one I couldn't begin to speculate about, but you might post a question in their forum to see if they have an idea.

Comment: Posted in the forum. Bruce doesn't believe URL Master module is causing the issues. Added an exception to not process that directory, but flickering is still occurring.

Comment: The Url Master module doesn't process 'physical' files.  You can easily get the Url Master module (and hence DNN) to ignore any Url by adding a regex pattern to the 'ignoreRegex' pattern.  But in the case of files that exist on the server, they won't be processed anyway.

Comment: Confirmed URL Master isn't the issue. Disabling it completely does not resolve the issue. Also, compression is not enabled. Any other thoughts on why this runs under a standard web instance on IIS, but not under DNN (or ASP.NET enabled)?

Comment: My guess is that IIS/DNN is still processing the files as dynamic content instead of static, but I don't know how to tell you to go about trying to prevent that.